# Зачем обрамлять таким образом функцию? Когда актуально применять?

Tags: php, функции

```
if (!function_exists('function_name')) {
    function function_name () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 3 >= 3.0.7, PHP 4, PHP 5

`function_exists` --  Возвращает TRUE, если данная функция определена
Описание

```
bool function_exists ( string function_name )
```

Проверяет, есть ли в списке определённых функций, встроенных и пользовательских, функция `function_name`. Возвращает `TRUE` в случае успешного завершения или `FALSE` в случае возникновения ошибки.

Погугли.

Comment: Вообще-то, ТС спрашивал, _зачем_ нужна такая конструкция, а не _что_ она делает. Поясню: эта конструкция защищает вас от случайного переопределения уже имеющейся функции. Для полного счастья можно к `if`'у пристроить `else`, в котором выкидывать сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: А, кажется понял, защищает от перегрузки функций? Это очередной прием из разряда "защита от самого себя". А где имеет смысл использовать? Может ли пригодится данная конструкция в классах?

Comment: например, в вашей версии php не реализована функция json_encode, и вы подключаете ее реализацию из внешнего файла.